# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop to read excel file data giving exception. WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, excel-interop

I have WPF application which reads excel file data and display it in on UI. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop` to read excel file data mainly `.xlsx`. On dev machine application is working fine but intalling and running this app on some computers it  giving me this error:

> ExcelRetrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)
>   What could be possible solution for this?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the target machine? Without Excel you can't use Office.Interop. There is a good alternative here http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes. MS Office installed on target machine.

Comment: I can only suggest to try to install PIA 2010 for Microsoft Office 2010 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508), also have you checked if your app is compiled for x86 and target machine is x64 or viceversa.

Comment: Intalled PIA. issue remains the same.Yes app is compiled for x86. but dev machine and target machine both are 64 bit. On dev machine is working fine.

Comment: On target machine do you have office64 or office32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Interop library has a number of massive disadvantages;  the first is that you need a copy of Excel installed on the target machine for it to work.

For this reason, our team never uses it.  I'd suggest the following alternatives.

http://npoi.codeplex.com ( older library for MS 2003 files .xls).

http://epplus.codeplex.com ( newer library with easier API that handles 2007 files .xlsx )

Neither requires Excel to be on the server.

Comment: Can't replace existing implementation,The all I can do is do some changes in the existing one.

Comment: With respect, if you have access to the code, you can pretty much do whatever you like.  Referencing an additional library is far less invasive than installing a copy of Excel on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Also **[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)**

- allows simple queries (Linq too) over **Excel** files,
- it's **free** and **easy to install** it on the server where you deploy your application,
- does **not require Office** installed on terget machine.

Comment: Does it need Office installed on target machines?

Comment: Actually it is desktop application so, does I need to install it on all target machines before running my app?

Comment: It is an Executable, it needs to be installed on all target machines, doesn't need Office installed, is from Microsoft, is free.